# Microsoft bot framework emulator is putting line numbers by itself

Tags: botframework

I am returning messages on the emulator and putting these messages in with line numbers , but apparently bot emulator has its specific way of numbering records , how can I stop that ? For example this piece of code is returning 1.Test 2.Test 3.Test while it shall return 1.Test 3.Test 5.Test

```
 public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
    {
        if (message.Type == "Message")
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("1. Test ");
            str.AppendLine("3. Test ");
            str.AppendLine("5. Test ");
            return message.CreateReplyMessage(str.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return HandleSystemMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the bot emulator is not enumeration your records.The text property of the messages is express in Markdown (see [documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#the-text-property-is-markdown)) and thus I guess the emulator is parsing your 1. as an ordered list.

You can try removing the dot (".") or escaping the character with a backslash ("\"). You can read more on how to escape characters [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown).